# Filtering among Exposed Filters : Parent/Child relationship between two Exposed Filter in Drupal View

Tags: ajax, views

I wanted to make a page with `exposed filter` search app in Drupal for a list of people.

I started by creating content type `Bio` and populated it as following:-

[image]

Then, I continued making a view with exposed filters of the fields of content type `Bio`. With the help of `Better Exposed Filters`, I am showing both Filters through Checkboxes through AJAX, as below:-

[image]

Now, until now, it's working fine. when I select a region or/and any city, the content updates according to that.

What I am hoping to create is a dependency between the `region` and `city`. All I want is that when I select any region in the `Filter by Region`, the lower filter values in the `Filter by City` automatically adjust and show me only the cities for which the `region field` in `Bio` is the selected city.

As an example, If a user selects `EMEA`, the `city` exposed filters should only show European cities.

I have been stuck in this for hours now. I have tried various solutions (`View Dependent Filters`and `Filter Fields`) but to no avail.

I'll be therefore very thankful for any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Look at my currently developing site's exposed filter(where 'Бренд' and 'Модель' fields): [Link](http://www.carroza.uz/kategoriya/gruzovik-razvozchik-morozhenogo)

If you want to achive this kind of functionality then you can achieve it like this. First you need to alter exposed filter function:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-VIEWS_NAME_VIEWS_DISPLAY') {
    if(!empty($form_state['values'])) {
      $form_state['input'] = array_merge($form_state['input'],$form_state['values']);
    }

    // Marks
    $mark_childs = populate_terms_by_vocab('transport_models', TRUE, FALSE);
    $form['field_adv_mark_tid']['#options'] = array('All' => t('--Выберите')) + $mark_childs;
    $form['field_adv_mark_tid']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'adv_mark_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'model-wrapper',
      'effect' => 'none',
      'progress' => array(
        'type' => 'throbber',
        'message' => '',
      ),
    );
    // marks end

    // Models begin
    $selectedMark = isset($form_state['input']['field_adv_mark_tid']) ? $form_state['input']['field_adv_mark_tid'] : NULL;

    if($selectedMark != NULL || $selectedMark != FALSE) {
      $model_childs = populate_terms_by_vocab('transport_models', FALSE, $selectedMark);
    }
    elseif($selectedMark == NULL || $selectedMark == FALSE) {
      $model_childs = array();
    }

    $form['field_adv_model_tid']['#options'] = array('All' => t('--Выберите')) + $model_childs;
    $form['field_adv_model_tid']['#prefix'] = '<div id="model-wrapper">';
    $form['field_adv_model_tid']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    // models end
  }
}

// This is an Ajax callback for $form['field_adv_mark_tid']['#ajax']
function adv_mark_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['field_adv_model_tid'];
}

// This is a helper function which returns terms (suitable for form selectlist, checkboxes or radios..)
function populate_terms_by_vocab($vocabulary_machine_name, $only_parents = TRUE, $parent = FALSE) {
  $vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vocabulary_machine_name);
  $terms = array();
  if($parent == FALSE) {
    $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocab->vid, 0, NULL, FALSE);
  }
  elseif($parent == TRUE) {
    $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocab->vid, $parent, NULL, FALSE);
  }

  $child_terms = array();
  foreach($terms as $key => $value) {
    if($only_parents && $terms[$key]->parents[0] == 0) {
      $child_terms[$terms[$key]->tid] = $terms[$key]->name;
    }
    elseif($only_parents == FALSE && $terms[$key]->parents[0] != 0) {
      $child_terms[$terms[$key]->tid] = $terms[$key]->name;
    }
  }

  return $child_terms;
}
```

I thinks the logic is the same.. In my case, I am adding to my entity type the two same term reference fields, and on content creation form I am displaying them as different parent field and child field (with pre-render function). By that, first field is holding the top level terms, the second field is holding child terms. And by views ui I am exposing them separately. And, that piece of code is displaying them as I want..

Comment: Thank you xurshid. I appreciate a lot. Where should I place this code?

Comment: @user219492 You can create a simple for that (just MY_MODULE.info file and MY_MODULE.module file is needed. Put this code in .module file) or put it in template.php.

Answer (score 0):

[Simple Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/shs) module seems to do what you are trying to achieve.

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies hierarchy.
>   The widget is available in node forms and as Views exposed filter.
>
> - add a new filter using the field set-up as "Simple hierarchical select" or
>     use "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; Simple hierarchical select)"
>     as a new filter
> - use "Simple hierarchical select" as selection type
> - select "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But It seems that it's not gonna help in Existing filters or fields within the content type. Any Idea on that? Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Any idea anyone guys? Simple Hierarchical Select only works with taxonomy terms, but I have fields in the content type `Bio` which I am using as Exposed Filters. Any help here?